# Error while installing SAP HANA Python Client Using PIP Install hdbcli

Tags: python, pip, hana

i am trying to install HANA Python Database Client in Anaconda using Jupyter Notebook,

I am getting following error.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli==2.4.171 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hdbcli==2.4.171

The hdbcli 2.4.171 library is available at https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The list of wheels at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/2.4.171/#files) lists only 64-bit wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.7. Wheels for 3.5-3.7 are only for w64. Either you have a different OS (MacOS X?) or a different version of Python (3.8?) or 32-bit version instead of 64.

Comment: Hi PHD thanks for your quick reply, my python version is 3.7.4 ; my OS is Win10 64 bit but my Computer hardware is x86 (32bit); so what could be real reason for this issue

Comment: Could be 32-bit Python. Run `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` if the command reports "32" that's the root of the problem.